# Groovy String array sort using float value

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have array of float values in string format. I was to sort the value and display in descending order.

How can I change this code to sort in float value?

```
class Sorting {
    def static main(args) {
        def a = ["13.17", "14.18", "15.19", "16.21", "17.22", "18.24", "19.25", "20.26", "21.26", "22.27", "23.28", "24.29", "25.30", "26.31", "27.32", "28.33", "29.34", "3.5", "30.35", "31.35", "32.36", "33.37", "34.38", "36.41", "4.6", "5.8", "6.9", "7.10"]
        println a.sort()
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parse elements as floats and then sort descending. Try this code:

```
def a = ["13.17", "14.18", "15.19", "16.21", "17.22", "18.24", "19.25", "20.26", "21.26", "22.27", "23.28", "24.29", "25.30", "26.31", "27.32", "28.33", "29.34", "3.5", "30.35", "31.35", "32.36", "33.37", "34.38", "36.41", "4.6", "5.8", "6.9", "7.10"]         

println a.collect{it as Float}.sort{-it}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another way:

```
a*.toFloat().sort().reverse()
```

Happy Learning ... ! :)

Comment: watch out! if `a` could be `null` then we should rather use `a*.toFloat()?.sort()?.reverse()` to prevent NPE